# Create a column that divides the other 2 columns using Pandas Apply()

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

Given a dataset -

```
country     year    cases   population
Afghanistan 1999    745     19987071
Brazil      1999    37737   172006362
China       1999    212258  1272915272
Afghanistan 2000    2666    20595360
Brazil      2000    80488   174504898
China       2000    213766  1280428583
```

The task is to get the ratio of cases to population using the pandas apply function, in a new column called "prevalence"

This is what I have written

```
def calc_prevalence(G):
    assert 'cases' in G.columns and 'population' in G.columns

    G_copy = G.copy()
    G_copy['prevalence'] = G_copy['cases','population'].apply(lambda x: (x['cases']/x['population']))
    display(G_copy)
```

but I am getting a

```
KeyError: ('cases', 'population')
```

Comment: Just simple `G['prevalence'] = G['cases']/G['population']`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that applies a named function to the dataframe without using lambda:

```
def calculate_ratio(row):
    return row['cases']/row['population']

df['prevalence'] = df.apply(calculate_ratio, axis = 1)

print(df)
#output:
       country  year   cases  population  prevalence
0  Afghanistan  1999     745    19987071    0.000037
1       Brazil  1999   37737   172006362    0.000219
2        China  1999  212258  1272915272    0.000167
3  Afghanistan  2000    2666    20595360    0.000129
4       Brazil  2000   80488   174504898    0.000461
5        China  2000  213766  1280428583    0.000167
```

Answer (score -1):

First, unless you've been explicitly told to use an apply function here for some reason, you can call the operation on the columns themselves resulting in a much faster vectorized operation. ie;

```
G_copy['prevalence']=G_copy['cases']/G_copy['population']
```

Finally, if you must use an apply for some reason, apply on the df instead of the two series;

```
G_copy['prevalence']=G_copy.apply(lambda row: row['cases']/row['population'],axis=1)
```